# Looping to create a lot of pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Just want to ask about some VBA excel stuff.

Now i'm doing a project to create a lot of pivot table with some value need to be added to the rows and value section. so i need a Macro to loop to create this pivot table and the value inside it.

here's the example of my code

```
Angka = Application.InputBox("Berapa Jumlah Agent", Type:=2)
For n = 1 To Angka
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim DestRng As Range
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range Table", "Enter Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set DestRng = Application.Selection
Set DestRng = Application.InputBox("Range Table", "Enter Range Destination", DestRng.Address, Type:=8)
Dim namaTable() As String
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    WorkRng, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'Pivot'!R8C1:R11C3", TableName:="namaTable(n)", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Pivot").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
Next n
```

I Cut some of the code for shorten purpose.

so i found out my error to be at line 12 -> Tablename:=namaTable(n)
i tried to use 1 table name such as "pivottable1", but the next pivot table will get an error message.

Question:

1. Can i Loop that pivot table using for function?
2. Is there some way to loop it ?

Thanks :D

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"namaTable(n)"`. You're passing that as a string literal instead of an array member.

Comment: Even without the quote, you're not assigning a value to `namaTable`. It's `Dim`ensioned on the line immediately before and is blank. Also, [PivotCaches.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create) only accepts 3 parameters (sourcetype, sourcedata, version) so I'm not sure where you're getting the extras. Also you should not be declaring variables within a loop because the will be declared/created over and over which can cause problems.  There's also a hanging `)`.

Comment: Also if you're creating "a lot of pivot tables" all looking at data in the same table/worksheet then you should not have to create several.  Pivot tables are intended to be one per dataset , which you customize on the fly with options and settings, filters, etc

Comment: hi, thanks for answering.

so basically pivotcaches.create just need 3 parameter? the extra method that appear is from macro recording. what i understand from my code is that every pivot has their own unique tablename, so when i need to edit the pivot table with vba code, i just need to access the tableName.